# Google map API does not return lat() or lon() only NAN

Tags: google-maps-api-3

About 2 days ago, my maps stopped working.  I am using 3.21 which appearantly was deprecated, and now my maps are blank.   Can anyone point me in the right direction?

www.ilac.com/maps and click on any name to pull up map page

Comment: Your page has a lot of code to wade through, it's not immediately obvious where the problem lies.  Can you use something like JSFiddle to produce a minimal example demonstrating the problem?

Answer (score 0):

This function no longer works:

```
function getLatLngFromStartPoint(start_point)
{
    var latlng = [];
    var c = 0;

    for(var name in start_point) {
        if (start_point.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
            latlng[c++] = start_point[name];
        }
    }

    return new google.maps.LatLng(latlng[0], latlng[1]);
}
```

[google.maps.LatLng](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#LatLng) objects don't have any documented properties.

You don't need to do that, start_point is already a google.maps.LatLng, so this (while silly), should work:

```
function getLatLngFromStartPoint(start_point)
{
    return start_point;
}
```

(might not be the only issue with your page...)